# Heroku looking for erb templates but only use HAML

Tags: deployment, heroku, haml, erb

I'm getting a `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method`message_body' for #<#:0x000000041d3630>):`error when I try to visit`polls/new.`

Heroku is looking for `app/views/polls/new.html.erb:4:in`_app_views_polls_new_html_erb__3114063437380502326_34508300'`but that file isn't even in my app.  All my views are in HAML.

Any tips here would be really really helpful!

Comment: Do you have the Haml gem installed and locked in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be - 'haml-rails' inside :assets or any other group in Gemfile

Move gem "haml-rails" to outside of group and it will work fine.